# Как обьединить несколько запросов в один?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

На сайте около 40 категорий, и выводятся они вот так:

```
<li>Комедии<sup>137</sup></li>
```

137 это число сколько в данной категории фильмов. Но так как категорий аж 40, делать 40 запросов при каждом обновлении страницы как то звучит не очень.

Я думаю может объединить все в один запрос или как будет лучше? И если лучше в один то как правильно?)

```sql
SELECT COUNT(cat) FROM film WHERE cat = 'comedy'
```

Вот таких 40 запросов в один)

Comment: `SELECT cat, COUNT(1) FROM film GROUP BY cat`

Answer (score 3):

Вот запрос. Вместо `name` должно быть ваше поле с названием:

```sql
SELECT `name`, `cat`, COUNT(`cat`) FROM `film` GROUP BY `cat`;
```

Comment: Какое поле? Ваще ничего не понял, точнее первую часть запроса...

Comment: @emtecif, это ваш первый запрос к БД? Я же написал, если у вас в БД есть поле с названием категории по русски, то вместо `name` впишите название своего поля

Answer (score 2):

Данный случай - это прекрасный пример использования оператора `GROUP BY`, который позволяет группировать записи по определенному полю, и при этом использовать агрегатные функции для подсчета сгруппированных результатов

```sql
SELECT cat, COUNT(1) cnt FROM film GROUP BY cat;
```

Поскольку стоит тег `pdo`, то уместно будет использовать функционал этой прекрасной библиотеки:

```
$sql = "SELECT cat, COUNT(1) cnt FROM film GROUP BY cat";
$categories = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIRS);
foreach ($categories as $name => $count) {
...
```

Comment: если бы еще написали к примеру как правильно вписать в цикле)

Answer (score -1):

При каждом новом запросе просто делаете конкатенацию строки:

```
$sql .= "select * from table where `column`='{$value}';";
```

А после уже и

```
$query = $mysqli->multi_query($sql);
```